# select value of specific cell in postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers

I am dealing with triggers in postgresql at the moment and am having trouble trying to compare a value from a newly inserted row to a value in an existing row where both the rows match on a certain attribute. Example:

I have table Class with values (class_id, class_name, enrollment_limit)
and another table Enrolled_in with values (student_id, class_id)

Basically I am trying to set a trigger when Students enroll in classes that have already reached its enrollment limit. Here is what my comparison code looks like.

```
 IF ((SELECT count(student_id) as num FROM class, enrolled_in
       where new.class_id = enrolled_in.class_id)
       > (select enroll_lmt from class
       where class_id = new.class_id ))  
       THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'too many enrolled';
```

I think my code after the greater than sign is faulty, but am not sure. I have been trying to figure this out for hours now. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a trigger `BEFORE INSERT`:

```
IF (SELECT count(*) >=
          (SELECT enroll_lmt
           FROM   class c
           WHERE  c.class_id = NEW.class_id )
    FROM   enrolled_in e
    WHERE  e.class_id = NEW.class_id
   ) THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'too many enrolled';
END IF;
```

The error was the needless cross join here: `FROM class, enrolled_in`. You don't need class for that query.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Apologies for the late reply!